# WP DB Location for "Next Post to Create" Index Value

Tags: multisite, database, wpdb, id

I have a malformed DB (no mystery here, I deleted some data directly rather than through the WP admin interface).  I've deleted all posts and meta for `400`+ but when I create a new post, the sequencing picks up where it left off (e.g. Post ID `434`), while I'm expecting it to be `400`.  Is there a value in the DB that tracks the ID of the "next post" WP will create?  I'd love to change that value to get back on track.

Comment: The posts table isn't just posts, it's also pages, revisions, menu items, and custom post types. is there a reason why you'd need it to resume at a particular place?

Comment: Really stupid, because it's a plugin bug, but another plugin is somehow tracking a separate index. Yes, it's horrific that the plugin is not pulling it's ID for association directly from the post itself, but that's what I'm up against and looking for the path of least resistance.

Comment: And yup, I'm aware of all the post types and that they all share the same ID index track.

Comment: [you have to alter the table and set AUTO_INCREMENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476512/changing-the-current-count-of-an-auto-increment-value-in-mysql)

Comment: @milo as an answer please :)